# PostgreSQL match on jsonb property value

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a where one of the columns is a jsonb object with a similar structure as this:

```
{
  "SomeObject": {
      "DoNotCheckMe": 111,
      "OrMe": 222
  },
  "MatchObject":{
      "MatchOnMe": 333,
      "OtherProperty": "Hello"
  }
}
```

I need a query which returns all rows where `MatchObject.MatchOnMe` has a specific value
With my current knowledge, I am able to get all rows from the table, that has that object and property on it with the given query:

```
SELECT id, value, info FROM table WHERE (info -> 'MatchObject')::jsonb ? 'MatchOnMe'
```

But I do not know how to get only those that matches a specific value of `MatchOnMe`, i.e. `123`

Am I close with the current check, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: `SELECT id, value, info FROM table WHERE info #> '{MatchObject,MatchOnMe}' = to_jsonb(123)`

Comment: Thanks, that works :)

What if I am checking up against multiple values within 'MatchObject' ? I.e. the match has to be: ```MatchOnMe``` is equal to '123' and ```OtherProperty``` should be 'Hello there'?

Comment: SELECT id, value, info FROM table WHERE info #> '{MatchObject,MatchOnMe}' = to_jsonb(123) AND info #> '{MatchObject,OtherProperty }' = to_jsonb('Hello there')